# How to display the name of the current Virtualenv?

Tags: zsh, python, oh-my-zsh, virtualenv

I'm using `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, `zsh`, `oh-my-zsh`, terminator, on Crunchbang.

I'm trying to display the name of the current `virtualenv` like so

```
workon example
(example)...
```

I've tried many solutions none seems to work, [here's my .zshrc](http://pastebin.com/C1SUnJur) file, I know it's no big deal to fix it but I can't find the right solution. It has been a long time since the last time I used Linux for Django development, I forgot what I used to do.

Right now, I see `username@crunchbang`, I can't tell which virtualenv I'm using.

Comment: I believe you're asking how to set your prompt so that it shows which virtualenv you're in, correct?

Comment: @slm yes exactly

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Shell's prompt

Inside your `virtualenv` environment is a file, `bin/activate`. You can edit this file to change your prompt to whatever you want it to look like. Specifically this section of the file:

```
...
else
    PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
fi
...
```

The variable `PS1` is a special variable that controls what a shell's prompt will look like. Changing its value will change your `virtualenv` prompt:

```
PS1="(this is my prompt) "
```

#### Example

1. Create a sample environment.

   ```
   $ virtualenv tst-env
   ```
2. When you're using `virtualenv` you typically source this file.

   ```
   $ cd $HOME/tst-env

   $ source bin/activate
   (tst-env)[saml@grinchy tst-env]$
   ```
3. After making the above change to the variable `PS1` in the `bin/activate` file my prompt is now this:

   ```
   $ source bin/activate
   (tst-env)
   ```

[Here are the official instructions on how to do this](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html).

Comment: tried it now, didn't fix it

Comment: here's my activate file http://pastebin.com/tZqdr1Yz

Comment: What happens when you source the `activate` file? Your file worked fine for me.

Comment: i see no output, so i can't tell what happens, the `virtualenv` is working other than that i see nothing, maybe it's `.zshrc` issue or `virtualenvwrapper`? can this issue be debugged? please note i have 2 virualenv executable files, the normal `virtualenv` and `virtualenv-2.7` is this normal or did `virtualenv` got downloaded twice? and this is how i installed virtualenv and virualenvwrapper in case it matters `sudo pip install virtualenv`

Comment: @Fischer - I just double checked it using `zsh` and it works with that too, so this is most likely an env. issue. Let's ignore the 2 virtualenv's setups for the time being. To debug you can enable it, `set -x`, in your shell and then re-run the `source activate` command again. You should see `PS1=` lines where the prompt is getting set.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply sir,I used `set -x`, this is the output of [source activate](http://pastebin.com/7fHKN0cD) and this is the output of [workon test-env](http://pastebin.com/yzzfGt9i)

Comment: Does the prompt change when you run this command? `export PS1='(test-env)'`

Comment: You're using `virtualenvwrapper` which is different than `virtualenv` BTW. I believe it calls `virtualenv` which is probably part of the problem. I believe there are similar changes that you need to make in this file: `$WORKON_HOME/postactivate` which is a virtualenvwrapper  file, not part of virtualenv. LMK if you have it.

Comment: the prompt doesn't change after i run`export PS1='(test-env)'` ... And `postactivate` i have 2 of these files, the first, is in the virtualenv project folder, the second is in `test-env/bin` they all contain the following lines 

`#!/bin/zsh`

`# This hook is run after this virtualenv is activated`

Comment: @Fischer - if you switch to `bash` for a second and try the `export ..` command does that work?

Comment: so they are practically empty, nothing other than the comments

Comment: tried that now, `bash` works fine, i can see the `(test-env)` and if i run `export PS1='(test-env)` the `username@crunchbang` will disapear, i'll see `>` where i enter commands and i press `ctrl-c` to exit

Comment: it maybe a zsh problem, if it cant be fixed i'll use bash

Comment: this is the output http://pastebin.com/MSQkfH4E

Comment: @Fischer - it's interesting that your `env` output doesn't include `PS1=...`. Can you try setting the `RPROMPT=...` variable like so: `export RPROMPT='(test-env) `?

Comment: when i do `export RPROMPT='(test-env)'` the `test-env` shows up, like so http://i.imgur.com/cx0q6b2.png but it doesn't matter if i'm using the virtualenv or not, it still shows until i exit the shell, when i start a new shell it will disapear

Comment: @Fischer - how about if you do this: `export PROMPT='(test-env) '`?

Comment: Oh, i didn't recognize that you wrote `export RPROMPT='(test-env)` on purpose, i thought you were missing a single quote :) so to recap: `export RPROMPT='(test-env)' the `test-env` shows up as i said in my previous comment, `export PROMPT='(test-env) '` does nothing, `workon test-env`  shows nothing at all, but `export PROMPT='(test-env)` shows `quote>` and i have to press `ctrl-c` to exit

Comment: @Fischer - that was a mistake on my part. So PROMPT didn't work out either?

Comment: no sir, it didn't, why bash is so different to zsh when it comes to virtualenv by the way?

Comment: @Fischer - are you using a prompt theme? http://askubuntu.com/questions/90254/cannot-change-zsh-prompt

Comment: no i'm not, should i try changing the theme? I'm using the default theme right now

Comment: @Fischer - don't know much about these prompt themes. Looking at that thread I would assume that using them in any capacity is a problem if you want to change the prompt.

Comment: i got it working, removed everything and added the following http://pastebin.com/kYreLrsy and it's working (don't know why, don't ask me :) ) but i noticed that i cant change themes, so it might have something to do with themes!I'll grab a configuration from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171563/whats-in-your-zshrc and i'll see what to do... this issue is apparently solved, now I'll have to see what is the connection between this issue and the themes (although i don't care about themes, not a designer :P) but i want to see why it caused me so much troubles!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `virtualenvwrapper` and `zsh` there are a number of zsh hooks in your `~/.virtualenvs/` directory that you can use to customize your environments. [Here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html) is a bit of info regarding these. You can force an update to `PS1` that will prepend the current working `virtualenv` to your shell prompt by adding:

```
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=$PS1
PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) $PS1"
builtin \export PS1
```

to `~/.virtualenvs/postactivate`. To remove the tag when you `deactivate`, add:

```
PS1=$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
builtin export PS1
```

to `~/.virtualenvs/postdeactivate`

The only (plausible) thing that should break this is resourcing `~/.zshrc` while working in a `virtualenv`

Comment: I believe you're postdeactivate script has a mistake. it should read


PS1=$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
builtin \export PS1

Comment: virtualenvwrapper already does this by default now. In venv created by virtualenvwrapper, the bin/activate script contains code to pre-pend the venv name to both zsh and bash prompts!

Comment: `echo "${VIRTUAL_ENV+(${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/}) }"`, but yeah it's already done when sourcing the venv nowadays

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to edit your `~/.zshrc`.

Since you are working with `virtualenvwrapper` it's possible to add options or hooks to `$WORKON_HOME/post(de)activate` files.

If you want to see more details consult [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#zsh-prompt).

**The above link allow me to do next:**

In my case `$WORKON_HOME=~/Envs` because I modified this path when I installed virtualenvwrapper; if you didn't you should have the folder `~/.virtualenvs`.

1. Open the file `postactivate` located in `$WORKON_HOME`
2. Add these lines:

   ```
   PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
   _OLD_RPROMPT="$RPROMPT"
   RPROMPT="%{${fg_bold[white]}%}(env: %{${fg[green]}%}`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`%{${fg_bold[white]}%})%{${reset_color}%} $RPROMPT"
   ```
3. Save and enjoy!

   You will obtain something like this: [image: done]
4. (OPTIONAL) If you want you could edit the `postdeactivate` file to add this line:

   ```
   RPROMPT="$_OLD_RPROMPT"
   ```

Comment: This seems to be copied from [the official documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#zsh-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the theme that is being used, you can add a function to retrieve the activated VIRTUAL_ENV base name and use it in the *PROMPT* variable in the ***.zsh-theme** file located at ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/ and that should do the trick!

For me it was the default 'oh-my-zsh' theme i.e. *'robbyrussels'* which was configured.

```
function virtualenv_info {
    [ $VIRTUAL_ENV ] && echo '('`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`') '
}

local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
PROMPT='${ret_status} $(virtualenv_info) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```

Adding the above code generated the below result:

[image]

**(kunkka.com)** is the virtualenv which I just deactivated.

After editing the theme file don't forget to source the .zshrc file.

```
-> source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

*[While this answer arguably strays a bit from answering the question as asked (though I attempt to at least partially do that, as well), I found my way to this question when looking for an answer that I knew existed for `venv` (instead of `virtualenv`), that I couldn't remember the exact details of (namely, the `--prompt` option, which both commands support).  I suspect I won't be the first, so here goes.]*

---

## with virtualenv / main answer:

First off, the basic answer to your core question is that you shouldn't *need* to do anything to get a prompt change, except to have an environment created, run its `activate` source file (which workon should effectively do for you), and have otherwise followed the installation docs (more below) — e.g. an extract from [the virtualenv docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html):

```
$ workon
$ mkvirtualenv mynewenv
New python executable in mynewenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools.............................................
..................................................................
..................................................................
done.
(mynewenv)$
```

This sort of behavior is what I'd expect from typing `workon example`, as you do in the question text, above (except you'd then get a prompt of `(example)$` instead of `(mynewenv)$`).

If you're not getting that, I'd make sure you're following all the proper steps for setting up `virtualenv`.  It's relatively unlikely you'd need to change anything in your `.zshrc` *[side note: your link to that is dead now]* — except as per the original [installation instructions](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file), which suggest adding the following (or a lazy-loading alternative, also listed there):

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And there should be nothing else... unless you're wanting the name to show up in a different place in your prompt or something (in which case, you may find some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406926/how-do-i-change-the-default-virtualenv-prompt) useful).

That said, there's also a question of simply naming the environment, which can be done either by naming the folder that stores the env, e.g.:

```
virtualenv example
```

Or by specifying a prompt when creating the environment with a different name, e.g.:

```
virtualenv env --prompt example
```

(This latter would create the files in a directory called `./env`, but the prompt when activating it would start with `(example)`.)

## with venv:

In modern (as I write this) python environments, it's also fairly common to just use the ships-with-python `venv` instead of (the `pip`-installed) `virtualenv` (though `virtualenv` still has adherents and reasons to use it — if I understand things correctly, `venv` is basically just a stripped-down version of `virtualenv`, with the latter having additional features and other improvements, not found in `venv`), and with `venv`, the equivalent of those last two commands (above) would be either:

```
python3 -m venv example
```

... or...

```
python3 -m venv env --prompt example
```

... respectively.

I hope this is useful (to someone)!

Answer (score 0):

I just test it on ubuntu 14.04 and i had the same problem. To fix it add this to your .zshrc

```
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

or run this in terminal

```
echo source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh >> ~/.zshrc
```

In Mac OS X I had to do

```
echo source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `bin/activate` file of your virtualenv from this

```
else
    PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${PS1-}"
fi
```

To this

```
else
    PS1="(your prompt) ${PS1-}"
fi
```

By maintaining the suffix you won't lose your `pwd` information from the terminal

Comment: It looks like you are implicitly saying that the accepted answer is wrong.  Why are you telling the OP to switch away from that answer?  And what does ``${PS1-}`` mean?

Comment: I am not saying it is wrong. I am adding an improvement. With the accepted answer.. I lost my current directory info from the terminal. I was not able to edit the original comment so i added my suggestion as an asnwer

And `${PS1-}` is what i had in my activate file. I just copy pasted the same.

Comment: Well, it looks like you are saying “Get rid of the \`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\` part.

Comment: Yes.. we need to keep the suffix to save the `pwd` information in our terminal.. the suffix can be  `${PS1-}` or just `$PS1` depending on the file